# How to compute a mean not using a mean function in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I need to compute a mean R avoiding using vectorized R functions. 
This is my code:

```
average <- function(x) {
for (s in seq_along(x)) {
 z <- 0
   z <- x + z 
  z <- (z / s) 
}
print(z) 
}

x_prob <- c(5, 19, 23, 56)
mean_x_prob <- average(x_prob)
mean_x_prob
```

For some reason, the answers I get are the following:

```
[1]  1.25  4.75  5.75 14.00
```

R basically divides every value I plug by the number of values. How to avoid it and compute a mean for the entire vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are looping over the sequence of the vector, use that as index to subset the value and add it to the initialized 'z and outside the loop, divide 'z' by the `length` of 'x'

```
average <- function(x) {
z <- 0
 for (s in seq_along(x)) {

     z <-   z + x[s]

   }
  z/length(x)
  }

average(x_prob)
#[1] 25.75
```

-checking with inbuilt `mean`

```
mean(x_prob)
#[1] 25.75
```